# Spark giving multiple datasource error on saving parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I am trying to learn spark and scala, on my trying to write the dataframe object of my result to parquet file by calling the parquet method, i am getting error as such

Code Base that fails:-

```
df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(outputPath)
```

This fails too

```
df2.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(outputPath)
```

Error Log:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Multiple sources found for parquet (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.parquet.ParquetDataSourceV2, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat), please specify the fully qualified class name.;
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:707)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:733)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:967)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
```

How ever if I called another method for the save, the code works properly,

This works fine:-

```
df2.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(outputPath)
```

Although I have a solution for the issue, i'd like to understand why the first approach is not working and how I can solve it.

The details of the specification i am using are:-
Scala 2.12.9
Java 1.8
Spark 2.4.4

P.S. This issue is only seen on spark-submit

Comment: Hi As per log there are two version of parquet in you environment and run time is not able to decide which one is correct .

Comment: so do I have to exclude something from the dependency in POM, how do I resolve that